# why computer becomes slow even after a program that used most memory

Tags: ubuntu, memory

I was testing some programs that would use a lot of memory. Then some program used nearly all memory (16G) in my computer. I forced to stop the program and I have 10G+ free memory now, but my computer becomes slow, I have to wait some seconds for opening even terminal. It needs a reboot to go back to normal. I want to know why and how to solve this problem besides rebooting.

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04 (But I think in Windows it happens too.)

CPU: i7-4710MQ

Memory: 16G

Disk: 500G

*Plus, I have no idea what tags should be added for this question.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When memory is full and a program needs the memory the operating system will swap the program to the virtual memory on the hard disk. Swapping out a ~10GB application to disk back and forth is very slow and time consuming (depending on the speed of your hard disk of course).

Each time you switch applications it will be retrieved from disk to memory. Or even worse background services might be loaded and unloaded continuously while they want to execute a small task. Overloading the disk IO and CPU.

You could [disable the swap-space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214805/how-do-i-disable-swap), then the application requesting memory will probably just crash instead, but the computer will stay fast ;-)

Other reads:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/48486/what-is-swap-memory